# Add a UIButton to UINavigationController programmatically

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios4

In Interface Builder you can drag a UIButton to the centre of a Navigation Controller, between the rightButtonItem and leftButtonItem.

I would like to do this programmatically, as i am not loading a xib.

I tried:

```
[self.navigationItem addSubview:myButton] // no luck
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:myButton] //no luck
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `titleView` of the `UINavigationItem` for the view controller you want the button to appear with.

```
[myAddedViewController.navigationItem setTitleView:myButton]
```